# SP looking for CSS files in the wrong place

Tags: 2013, css, custom-masterpage, 404

Environment: SP2013 Enterprise, custom master page, Dreamweaver

I've made a custom master page complete with its own CSS. My style sheets are linked near the bottom of the `<head>` like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://server/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomPage/css/style.css">
```

There are 5 style sheets in all, each for a different breakpoint (wide/narrow/mobile/etc). When I publish and preview the master page, only a small set of the main `style.css` sheet seems to be obeyed (cannot establish a reason yet). Watching the transaction through Fiddler I noticed that in addition to the correct location for the style sheets, SharePoint is also trying to get them from `/_layouts/15/css/style.css` and returning a 404.

I was under the impression that you can store custom style sheets anywhere, so long as the link to them is correct. So why is SharePoint looking for them in the `_layouts` folder in addition to the linked location? Could this be related to the styles not being obeyed?